# the 'animate()' function my code doesn't work but 'css()' does. what's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

this piece of code works only when i write

```
.css()
```

, but not

```
.animate()
```

What is the reason?

the whole thing:

```html
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
$('.banner').animate({'background':'linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%'}, 800);
$('.banner h1').animate({
    'background': 'linear-gradient(to left, black 50%, white 50%', '-webkit-background-clip': 'text', '-webkit-text-fill-color': 'transparent'
    }, 800)
```

Comment: Welcome on board, but can you define what *works*?

Comment: @vahdet this works: $('.banner').css({'background':'linear-gradient(to right, black 50%, white 50%'}); but when i write animate() it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

> All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color plugin is used). Property values are treated as a number of pixels unless otherwise specified. The units em and % can be specified where applicable.

What you're trying to animate doesn't fit the description of what it says it can animate.

Comment: oh thank you!! then.. how can i make the background change smoothly?

Comment: @valeria - You'll need to either find a plugin that does it, or do the animation yourself with `setInterval` and [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).